# Explanation of Tata's words

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, narcos

In the episode [Deutschland 93](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5714402/) from the second season of *Narcos* Tata meets Murphy in the plane from Germany to Colombia and [says](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=narcos-2015&episode=s02e07) to him:

> I hope you enjoyed Germany.

It seems that the most plausible explanation is that she recognised him as a DEA agent and noticed that he spent all his time in Germany in the airport, just like she did. However I didn't notice any sign of sarcasm in her voice, she seemed to be completely emotionless when saying this.

This leads to a second possibility that she simply remembered him from the flight to Germany and it was just some small talk. However if this is the case then I have really hard time understanding the purpose of adding this scene in the first place.

Is it one of these two options or something else? What is the actual meaning of this scene?

Comment: I would say she surely recognized him and she was being sarcastic, I don't think she was in a situation where she would just make nice comments to strangers, specially american looking ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-watched the scene and noticed that I missed an important detail. As I mentioned in my question, Tata seems to be emotionless during the short interaction itself, but when it ends we can see her coming back to her sit. After sitting, she gives Murphy (now heading to the toilet) a long, angry look. This clearly proves that she knew who she was talking to and that she sarcastically commented the fact that Murphy spent all his time in Germany in the airport.